# jQuery sliding notice on top of screen

Tags: jquery-ui

With JQuery UI I am looking to have a small header bar slide down after the page loads with a single line of text that the user can click on.

Is there a slide-from-the-top-and-dismiss JQuery UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some links to tutorials

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-top-panel-with-jquery/

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/sliding-top-menu-with-jquery